# ajax callback function in sequence

Tags: jquery, ajax

I I tried to call function(b) after function(a) is completed.
But alert message appears before function(a) is done.
your brilliant solution will be respected.

```
$.ajax({
    url : "action.do",
    .....code....
}).done(function(a){

    ...code...

}).then(function(b){

    alert("hello");

});
```

Comment: what you doing in function a()..its any another ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

`done` doesn't work like a proper promise `then` function does. To do this, you'd want to use `then` and be sure to return the promise from the `ajax` call, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "action.do",
    // .....code....
}).then(function(a){
// ^^^^
    return $.ajax({
//  ^^^^^^
        url : "action.do",
        // .....code....
    });
}).then(function(b){
    alert("hello");
});
```

I believe you need at least jQuery v1.8 for this, but double-check with the version you're using, there was a lot of work across multiple versions to make jQuery's `Deferred` and promises compatible with the Promises/A+ spec and (therefore) the ES2015 (aka "ES6") spec's promises.

Answer (score -1):

Because the then() always does before .done()

.done() has only one callback and it is the success callback

.then() has both success and fail callbacks

Answer (score -1):

.then() is used to manipulate a promise. It has 2 callbacks, success and failure. So done is the success callback function of .then().

You can modify the code in two of the following ways:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "action.do",
    .....code....
}).done(function(a){

    ...code...
    alert("hello");
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url : "action.do",
    .....code....
}).then(function(b){

    alert("hello");

});
```

Ideally .then() is like the below code:

```
.then(function(){
    ...success case...(.done() scenario)
},function(){
    ...failure case... (.fail() scenario)
});
```